# Selecting only points which are intersecting line layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have large number of points(As a point layer) and few line(Roads basically), how do I remove points which are not falling on line layer.

I tried several methods like-

1. Join attribute by location,
2. Intersect
3. Clipping etc,

Some how QGIS gets crashed while running algorithm.

I am using QGIS 2.18.14 and QGIS 2.18.14

Comment: The issue with QGIS crashing may result from invalid geometry in one of the layers. Use the Geometry Checker plugin to find and fix errors before running the tools.

Answer (score 3):

The possibility that a certain point falls onto a certain line is unlikely.
I recommend to calculate a buffer around your line (for example: 10m) and compute the intersection with the already given tool `Vector > Geoprocessing Tool > Intersection` which should be left over just the "intersecting" points.

The distance threshold for the boundary is up to you but depends on your data quality and requirements